# WSO2ESB Rest API with WSO2MB

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I have three applications which should communicate together with bandwitch limit over 100,000 users.

We decide to use WSO2MB with WSO2ESB to publish messages between apps.

The problem is that the target.endpoint do not get the message and I don't know why.

```
  <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="School" context="/schools">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/" faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message Flow" value="--- Schools POST ---"></property>
         </log>
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"></property>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"></property>
         <property name="target.endpoint" value="Test.Endpoint"></property>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message Flow" value="--- Schools POST ---"></property>
         </log>
         <store messageStore="JMSMS"></store>
         <log level="full"></log>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

MessageStore

```
<messageStore name="JMSMS" class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.destination">JMSMS</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.connection.factory">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.username">admin</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.password">admin</parameter>
   <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

Message Processor

```
<messageProcessor name="JMSMS" class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" targetEndpoint="Test.Endpoint" messageStore="JMSMS" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
   <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

Jndi.properties

```
connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5673'
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5673'

queue.JMSMS=JMSMS
```

**EDIT:**
Test.Endpoint

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test.Endpoint">
   <http method="post" uri-template="http://10.0.2.2:8000/super/test"/>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the below property. But you haven't defined the endpoint in your synapse.

```
 <property name="target.endpoint" value="Test.Endpoint"></property>
```

If you have defined the value as Test.Endpoint there should be an endpoint defined.

E.g.,

```
  <endpoint name="Test.Endpoint">
      <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
   </endpoint>
```

Please check our sample document : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+702%3A+Introduction+to+Message+Forwarding+Processor

Comment: I had an endpoint Test.Endpoint                                                                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test.Endpoint">
   <http method="post" uri-template="http://10.0.2.2:8000/super/test"/>
</endpoint>